# Broadcast receiver with activity inheritance

Tags: java, android, kotlin, inheritance

I have a question. I have 2 activities in each I initialize the broadcast receiver to obtain internet connection changes. After changes are received, I notify the user about it by displaying some text on the screen.

In order not to write the code several times, I created BroadcastActivity that inherits from AppCompatActivity.

Now I pass views with super() to BroadcastActivity and manipulate with views (Change texts, visibilities etc.).

Question is: Is it best practice to do so or is there a more elegant solution? And if it can lead to memory leaks?

Thank you for your help!

Example of BroadcastActivity

```
open class BroadcastActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnConnectionChangeListener {
    //some code
}
```

And example of activity (Secondary activity structure similar to this)

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastActivity{
    //some code
}
```

P.S. BroadcastActivity written on Kotlin and MainActivity on Java.

P.S. 2 At this moment I can't switch to single activity and looking for temporary solution.

Comment: `Is it best practice to do so or is there a more elegant solution?` don't use more than one activity. have one activity with fragments. your activity can handle these kinds of requirements, every fragment then just handles whatever you need them to do, but you can share data way better with this approach

Comment: @a_local_nobody at the moment I can't switch to single activity and looking for a workaround. I also modified the question to add this clarification. Thanks you.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with listening to internet connection changes but you might be able to move that code to an Application class maybe?

Comment: @IvoBeckers yip, that would be a good suggestion too

Comment: Offtopic really, because you'd just extract a BroadcastReceiver into a class of it's own, and hook it up with `activityLifecycle`.

Comment: @Shark feel free to read the question again. I made a solution with inheritance and asking if so is the best practice to do so? Thanks

Comment: @IvoBeckers Thanks for your answer I will try this

Comment: And that's exactly why i said, "it's offtopic because it's a opinion-based thing and not a very factual one / based only on facts". IMO, it's far from a best practice, and is also not a very good one. Someone might argue that there's nothing wrong with it and it's been working "just fine" for the past 10 years. We're both wrong, and we're both right at the same time. And my opinion is - if you're going that way, instead of subclassing AppCompatActivity, you could have just made an extension function that registers/unregisters the BroadcastReceiver in appropriate lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further elaborate on my comment, here's something "better" (again, in my personal opinion) ...

ActivityKtx.kt:

```
fun Activity.applyBroadcastReceiver(broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver) {
    lifecycle.addObserver(
        BroadcastReceiverObserver(
            BroadcastReceiverConfigurationImpl(broadcastReceiver, this)
        )
    )
}
```

BroadcastReceiverObserver.kt:

```
/**
 * Class implementing [DefaultLifecycleObserver] which is in charge of delegating setting the
 * [BroadcastReceiver]'s registration status.
 * Registers in [Activity.onResume] and unregisters in [Activity.onPause]
 */
class BroadcastReceiverObserver(
    val broadcastReceiverConfig: BroadcastReceiverConfiguration
) : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    var isBroadcastReceiverRegistered = false

    override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onResume(owner)
        if (isBroadcastReceiverRegistered.not()) {
            broadcastReceiverConfig.registerBroadcastReceiver()
            isBroadcastReceiverRegistered = true
        }

    }

    override fun onStop(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        if (isBroadcastReceiverRegistered) {
            isBroadcastReceiverRegistered = false
            broadcastReceiverConfig.unregisterBroadcastReceiver()
        }
        super.onStop(owner)
    }

    // add same things for onStart() and onPause()
}

/**
 * Base class for handling a [BroadcastReceiver] registration status
 */
abstract class BroadcastReceiverConfiguration {
    abstract fun registerBroadcastReceiver()
    abstract fun unregisterBroadcastReceiver()
}

/**
 * Base class for handling the broadcast receiver
 *
 * @see [BroadcastReceiverObserver]
 */
class BroadcastReceiverConfigurationImpl constructor(
    private val broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver,
    private val hostActivity: Activity
) : BroadcastReceiverConfiguration() {
    
    override fun registerBroadcastReceiver() {
        //ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION - deprecated
        hostActivity.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
    }

    override fun unregisterBroadcastReceiver() {
        hostActivity.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
    }
}
```

then just use it like this:

SomeActivity.kt:

```
class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        applyBroadcastReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver)
    }
```

and voila. zero need for subclassing the Activity / AppCompatActivity / MyBaseActivity or whatever.

Comment: Thank for your answer, by the way what is topic name will suitable for this case on your opinion?

Comment: @PavelMaltsev none, it's not the topic name that's problematic; it's the question's content. Any question that revolves solely on "do you think ..." or "do you suggest I use A or B" without context on why A and B are being considered is off-topic for the same opinion-based reason i mentioned earlier. It literally boils down to a "Should I paint my house red or blue?", people liking red will vote red, people liking blue will vote blue, people not liking red will say paint it black, some people will say "do whatever everyone else is doing, paint it white" and the answer isn't really useful.

Comment: But if we were to really refactor the question, then a more suitable name would be "How to apply BroadcastReceiver to listen for internet connectivity changes for API 21+ and below?" and then work from there. Show what you tried, people will suggest using a repository for that, you'll update your answer with the BroadcastReceiverActivity, someone comes along and posts this answer as an answer, gets downvoted for not answering the question, but my answer works fine for pre-Q (or P) APIs.  This way, you're really masking it as an X/Y question.

Comment: @PavelMaltsev your real problem is "how to listen for internet connetivity changes on pre-P and post-P APIs". You're masking it as "how do i do this elegantly with broadcast receivers and should i inherit Activity to do it". However, while the answer to first question is something different than this, answer to second question is **stay away from inheritance of things you cannot control, and use composition instead. Once the thing changes, your code breaks and acts unexpectedly. Composition-based approach doesn't have that problem**. And this answer uses composition instead.